# Fetch external template script by web browser

Tags: html, ajax, templates, fetch

Modern client side template libraries use  tags of type text/html.

Every tutorial / article about it I read shows an example of such script which is embedded to the html page.

Are you aware of any way to make an external text/html script which would be loaded by the browser without using ajax or autogenerating the page on the server side?

I know that these two approaches are possible, but I want to be KISS as possible.

A page with many templates in it becomes a mess quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time and some experience I think I know an answer which would satisfy my question.
The method is robust and easy to use.

There is a script loader which is called require.js. It handles loading javascripts, text files and i18n data from server asynchronously. It is quite simple to set up.

Additionally it allows to preprocess the site and inline those javascripts/text files for use in production mode.

This way development with good structure is easy and it also should work fast (no additional requests) for users.

Answer (score 0):

What templating engine are you using? Most will accept a string in which case you can just request the template file via AJAX and provide the string to the template engine.

Comment: I have explicitly said that I know about ajax solution, but I don't want to use it for simplicity sake.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. So you don't want to include the template in the HTML, and you don't want to load it via AJAX. You could do `<script id="TEMPLATE_ID" type="text/html" src="/path/to/template"></script>`, then reference that template by ID in your templating code.

Comment: so .. when I "reference that template by ID" will it load from server? I'm using jquery templates

Comment: When the page loads, the browser will see the script tag and automatically fetch it for you. Just make sure to wrap your template calls in `$(document).ready(function(){…});`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm using knockout.js for model <-> template binding, so it may be the issue. I'll maybe try tomorrow with your method and plain jquery templates.

Comment: I've never tried this particular method, but I believe it should work. Do let me know how it turns out :)